# R : warning : The `x` argument of `as_tibble.matrix()` must have unique column names if `.name_repair` is omitted as of tibble 2.0.0

Tags: r

```
umap_results$layout
  #         [,1]         [,2]
  #[1,] -1.041482307  1.389173771
  #[2,]  0.686965089  2.671049064
  #[3,] -2.170222731 -0.347427768
  #[4,] -2.028087128  2.476267251
  #[5,] -1.070957496 -0.354622580
  #[6,] -1.174079325 -1.174164172
  #[7,] -2.777973062  2.372981619
  #[8,] -1.237910856  0.798519857
  #[9,] -1.551065808  1.186282879
  #[10,] -2.686569147  2.606249490

umap_results_tbl <- umap_results$layout %>%
  as_tibble()%>%
  mutate(symbol = stock_date_matrix_tbl$symbol)

#symbol is just a simple column with alphabets e.g. symbol = #c(A,AL,AP)
```

I do not understand why the error tells me to input unique column while I did give a unique column(layout). Can you please explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just a warning. The warning is issued the object input is a `matrix` and it doesn't have any column names.

```
library(tibble)
cbind(1:5, 6:10) %>% 
        as_tibble()
```

There is an option to override the `warning` if we use the `.name_repair` and by default it uses the option `check_unique`

```
cbind(1:5, 6:10) %>%
     as_tibble(.name_repair = 'unique')
```

Comment: so warning is not very bothering compared to an error? can I ignore them like most of the cases?

Comment: @hased you can ignore those warning.  It is just a friendly warning suggesting that they don't have any column names